# Login Screen shows nothing on the pages

Tags: python, kivy

I have the code for an app I am creating so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import json
from datetime import datetime
 
Builder.load_file('design.kv')
 
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def sign_up(self):
        print("Sign up button pressed")
        self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen"
    def login(self, uname, pword):
        with open("users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)
        if uname in users and users[uname]['password'] == pword:
            self.manager.current = 'login_screeen_success'
 
 
 
class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass
 
class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    def add_user(self, uname, pword):
        with open("users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)
            print(users)
 
            users[uname] = {'username': uname, 'password': pword,
            'created': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%m-%S")}
 
            with open("users.json", "w") as file:
                json.dump(users, file)
 
            self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen_success"
 
class SignUpScreenSuccess(Screen):
    def go_to_login(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"
 
class LoginScreenSuccess(Screen):
    def log_out(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        self.manager.current = "login_screen"
 
 
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

I also have my kivy code over here too:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label:
                text: "User Login"
            TextInput:
                id: username
                hint_text: "Username"
            TextInput:
                id: password
                hint_text: "Password"
            Button:
                text: "Login"
                on_press: root.login(root.ids.username.text, root.ids.password.text)
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: "Forgot Password"
            Button:
                text: "Sign Up"
                on_press: root.sign_up()
 
<SignUpScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Sign up for a space journey!"
        TextInput:
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            id: password
            hint_text: "Password"
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.add_user(root.ids.username.text, root.ids.password.text)
 
<SignUpScreenSuccess>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Sign up successful"
        Button:
            text: "Login page"
            on_press: root.go_to_login()
 
<LoginScreenSucces>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button: 
            text: "Logout"
            on_press: log_out()
        Label:
            text: "How do you feel?"
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Things to try: happy, sad, unloved"
        Button:
            text: "Enlighten me"
        Label:
            text: ""
 
<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
        name: "login_screen"
    SignUpScreen:
        name: "sign_up_screen"
    SignUpScreenSuccess:
        name: "sign_up_screen_success"
    LoginScreenSuccess:
        name: "login_screeen_success"
```

Everything is working fine but when click login after inputting username and password, it doesn't show anything on the `LoginScreenSuccess` page. I am not sure why. Can somebody please help. I have been looking for a solution but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo. in your `kv`, change `<LoginScreenSucces>:` to `<LoginScreenSuccess>:` (missing trailing `s`).